# set-aduser inside foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the below script to change three things on an AD account. I want it to expire the account, change an attribute, and append disabled account to the current description. It does everything except append the description. As it stands the script just replaces the description field with Disabled Account instead of append it to what is already there.

```
$Yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$DisableUserList = Get-Content C:\Myscripts\test.csv
$DisableUsers = foreach ($user in $DisableUserList) { get-aduser -filter { mail -eq $user } }


ForEach ($user in $DisableUsers) {
        Set-ADUser $user -Description "Disabled Account $($_.Description)" -AccountExpirationDate $Yesterday -replace @{ businesscategory = "21" }
}
```

The .csv file only has one column of email addresses.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Skip the `set-aduser` for a moment.  What happens if you just put a `Write-host "Disabled Account $($_.Description)"` in that for loop?

Comment: It writes Disabled Account twice for the 2 records in the .csv file.

Comment: Did your test accounts already have the description updated to be 'disabled account'?  Try change your test accounts to have something else in them?

Comment: Yes, both accounts had a different description field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `$($_.Description)` part of your `Set-ADUser` command is empty.  The reason is that `Get-ADUser` doesn't retrieve the account's description by default. You need to explicitly ask for it in your command like this:

```
get-aduser -filter { mail -eq $user } -Properties Description
```

Your other problem is that you're not referencing your disabled user properly within your final loop.  You're currently using `ForEach ($user in $DisabledUsers)` which means to access properties on each user they need to be prefixed with `$user.MyProperty` instead of `$_.MyProperty`.  If you want to use the `$_` notation, you need to change the style of your for loop to this:

```
$DisabledUsers | ForEach-Object {
```

You can also shorten that to just:

```
$DisabledUsers | % {
```

Finally, you say you want to **append** (add to the end) your text to the current description, but your code is currently trying to **prepend** (add to the beginning).  Assuming you do actually want to append, you'd need to change your description string definition to this:

```
-Description "$($_.Description) Disabled Account"
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, I tried that while I was waiting for a response, but now it just replaces the description field instead of append it.

Comment: I thought you said replacing the description is what was happening originally and you wanted it to append?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'll have to update the post as I can see how that is confusing. I want the script to append Disabled Account to the current description field of the account.

Comment: Added some more to my answer

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the $_.Description to $user.Description and that fixed my issue. I appreciate your time!